# Clipboard over SSH session through VIM

Tags: ssh, vim

I have a server running SSH, when I edit a file with vim on the remote server, `:y+` doesn't work since the VIM binary on that linux system wasn't compiled with X support.

(E488: Trailing characters)

So how should I share the clipboard? Just transparently like what I do on local system

Answer (score 2):

Use a vim compiled with X support instead, e.g. `gvim -v`, along with X forwarding in SSH.

Comment: It's counter-intuitive that this will work even *without* xserver on the server side.  Worked for me on Debian Wheezy server using vim-gtk which replaced old vim (using debian-alternatives) and had only few dependencies.  No pulling in of whole xserver to my headless VPS.  (Surprisingly enough, the sshd even had X11 forwarding on by default)