# How to keep `CLIPBOARD` content from XTerm after closing it? (Like Firefox or Leafpad does for example.)

Tags: x11, xorg, xterm, clipboard, x-server

I wanted to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> for Copy-and-Paste within XTerm and other applications, so I added

```
XTerm*vt100.translations: #override \
    Shift Ctrl <Key> C: copy-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
    Shift Ctrl <Key> V: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)
```

to my `~/.Xresources`. Copy-and-Paste works fine, as long as I don't close XTerm. Then, all `CLIPBOARD` content is lost. The same problem arises when using

```
XTerm*vt100.selectToClipboard: true
```

where as soon as text gets selected, it is copied directly to `CLIPBOARD` (instead of to `PRIMARY` - or maybe to both?) but is only available as long as XTerm is running.

So, I read some more on `CLIPBOARD`

- https://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html
- https://mutelight.org/subtleties-of-the-x-clipboard
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection
- [How to make Shift+Insert paste selection after closing window with selection?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82311/how-to-make-shiftinsert-paste-selection-after-closing-window-with-selection/82325)
- https://burrows.svbtle.com/universal-copy-paste-in-linux

... but couldn't find a definitive answer. There seem to exist tools, which are able to sync `CLIPBOARD` and `PRIMARY` for example. Or make `CLIPBOARD` content persistent. Or some kind of `CLIPBOARD` history. But I'm not sure that this is what I'm looking for, here.

**For example:** If `CLIPBOARD` content doesn't really leave the application and other programs have to "ask" the original application for the content of `CLIPBOARD`, it makes sense that this would only be possible as long as this program is running. However, how does the `CLIPBOARD` selected text from Firefox or Leafpad stay available, even though the program has been closed? How does Firefox/Leafpad do this? They don't use an external tool, do they?!

Comment: Related articles on [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_manager).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under X, there isn't really a clipboard. All selections (primary, secondary clipboard) are copied by having the two X clients that are involved talk to each other. (See for example the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection) for details).

That means if one X client holding the selection is no longer running, the selection is gone.

What you can do is to run *another* client, e.g. `xclipboard`, which immediately copies the selection from your `xterm` (or any other X client) as soon as it is made, and is able to participate in the communication described above even when `xterm` is no longer running. Of course, now you have to keep `xclipboard` running ...

I have never observed that Firefox somehow does things differently, but if the selection is indeed available after Firefox is closed, some other X client must still be running, possibly something that is part of your desktop. So yes, Firefox must use some sort of external tool (but as I said, I have not observed this myself. But then, I'm not using a "desktop" in this sense, just `fvwm`).